# Ios push notification in ionic application

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, notifications, push

Push notification not receiving to my IOS device which is working fine for android. I am using Firebase to send notification for android and IOS, I have configured the google-service-info.plist file to my Firebase account and enabled push notification in Xcode before taking the build. But I am not able to receive the notification, is there any additional configuration that I required to change for IOS? Why am not getting push notification which works fine by default for android?

I am able to get device token of IOS that am using this token to trigger notification.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still having this problem with ios push notification. This is how i solved it. 
Login into your apple developer account  and create an APNs Authentication key (.p8 file). 
Then upload it to your firebase console in the cloud messaging tab.